# Custom click handler for Semantic Zoom

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a GridView in SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView. When I set the GridViews ItemClick it never gets called. How do I put a custom action to the click? I want to do a slihtly different logic.

(Please do not answer like you should not do this, it is the clients wish and the cannot be persuaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom Grid implementing ISemanticZoomInformation and used it in the ZoomedOutView, the GridView as its child.

I summed it up in a blog post: http://blog.kulman.sk/customizing-semantic-zoom-in-windows-8-apps/